# Spring 3.0 interceptor and servlets

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

I am new to spring 3.0. My issues is that i have a HTML form in which action is pointing to a servlet.
Now I have written an interceptor. But this request is not going through that interceptor.

So my question is does the request for a servlet goes through a interceptor in Springs?
(I though that all request in a application with spring mvc goes through the interceptor defined)

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: hove you configured the interceptor?

Comment: In Spring we only have DispatcherServlet and some other internal servlets. So in your case action must be pointing to a controller. And you should map that interceptor to a controller. Show your mappings.

Comment: Interceptor is defined as a normal bean in the applicationContext.xml file and the interceptor class extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter. And the servlet is mapped in the web.xml.                                                           I cannot convert it to a controller as its existing code and cannot change from servlet to controller.